# Django: This site can’t be reached : localhost refused to connect

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, windows-10, django-admin

I am a newbie to the django and doing a course from udemy and got stuck at the admin page. I am unable to load the django default admin login page. It throws the following error: This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.

I am still at the very beginning of the course and just created a function in the model.py file and made the migrations and tried accessing the default login page. Here's the code:

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    phone_no = models.IntegerField()
```

I have tried all the steps mentioned in the previous answers. But still, the issue isn't resolved. I strongly feel that it is due to system settings regarding the localhost.

No error displayed in the command prompt. I have changed my firewall settings, tried adding localhost, '*' and every other alternative that I've found.

Please help..!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try to solve the issue on the Django side of life?
Go ahead and allow the localhost within your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` like so:

**settings.py**

```
[...]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
    'localhost'
]

[...]
```

Comment: Thank you Jonas for responding. Yeah, I've tried updating the 'ALLOWED_HOSTS' earlier with the said localhost and '127.0.0.1', still, the issue isn't resolved. I haven't done much coding to look after if there are any coding issues.